# How can I animate a custom view (ImageView) programmatically?

Tags: android, animation, view, animated-gif

I want to animate a custom view programmatically. I want it to only animate in the position where it is declare in the xml file, and I don't want it to mess the layout. Also this animation is affected by other factor so the android Animation class is out of the question.

I have test this sample [tutorial](http://obviam.net/index.php/sprite-animation-with-android/) and watch this [videos](http://www.mybringback.com/series/android-basics/). My problem is that most tutorial is for animating a sprite into a canvas where you will trace your sprite's location.

How can you animate the custom view without affecting layout and without using the Android Animation class?

Edited:
The custom view will act as a animated-gif and will toggle another set of frames whenever an event activates it.

Comment: What do you want to do? How do you want to animate it?

Comment: The animation is LIKE a loading bar, it runs with respect to time, but when an event happened another set of animation will play on that view. The animation must only affect the custom view.

Comment: With AnimationDrawable you can easily toggle to another set of frames if you call:   rocketImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.<<Some other animation-list>>); when you need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want "frame by frame" animation that just "runs" like an animated gif, you can follow:
[drawable-animation official tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html).

Quoting from the tutorial:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="true">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rocket_thrust1" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rocket_thrust2" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rocket_thrust3" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

and in your code

```
AnimationDrawable rocketAnimation;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  ImageView rocketImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rocket_image);
  rocketImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rocket_thrust);
  rocketAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) rocketImage.getBackground();
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    rocketAnimation.start();
    return true;
  }
  return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: AnimationDrawable class is what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

you can create animation XML and apply that animation from program to your ImageView check following example

you can start animation for your customized view just call `viewobject.startAnimation(animationobject);`

**animation.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shareInterpolator="false">
<scale
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXScale="1.0" 
    android:toXScale="1.4" 
    android:fromYScale="1.0" 
    android:toYScale="0.6" 
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:fillAfter="false"
    android:duration="700" />
<set
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:startOffset="700">
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1.4" 
        android:toXScale="0.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.6"
        android:toYScale="0.0" 
        android:pivotX="50%" 
        android:pivotY="50%" 
        android:duration="400" />
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="0" 
        android:toDegrees="-45"
        android:toYScale="0.0" 
        android:pivotX="50%" 
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="400" />
</set>
```

your **main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/hello"
/>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

then your activity class **myActivity.java**

```
public class myActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);

    //create animation class object
    Animation hyperspaceJump = 
        AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.hyperspace_jump);
    //start animation for image
    image.startAnimation(hyperspaceJump);
}
}
```